# How to set up custom fields configuration schema in Jira?

Tags: customization, jira

I need to set up the custom schema for bug. I don't plan to do estimation of bug, put them on Agile board, some other fields should be hide also. I need to decrease number of fields in bug for my company users. I tried it several times, but unsuccessfully. Please, provide me steps.
Do I need create issue type schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you are interesting in customizing fields configuration for specific issue type. What you need is to setup a [field configuration](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Specifying+Field+Behaviour) for your case and then map it to a specific issue type in a [field configuration scheme](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Associating+Field+Behaviour+with+Issue+Types). This can be either existing scheme or you can setup a new one. Scheme then should be associated with a project you want these changes to be applied to. This [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Fields+and+Screens) can also be helpful for you in order to understand the general concept of configuring fields and screens.

Comment: ok, 1. I've created issue type schema and applied it to Bug, 2. than I create new field configuration and mapped it with Bug in field configuration schema. But I cannot map schema to project :( how to finish it?

Comment: The various JIRA schemes and how they work together is explained in Practical JIRA Administration (O'Reilly) if that helps

Comment: In JIRA menu on the top of a JIRA screen go to Projects, find your project and click on it. This will show you a project screen. Go to administration tab then scroll down and find a "Fields" section. Click on field scheme which is associated with your project. This will open you field configuration screen. In top right corner of the screen you can see "Actions" button. Click it and then choose "Use a different scheme".